# APIG/Lambda for hosting multiple micro services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

What is the AWS recommendation for hosting multiple micro-services? can we host all of them on same APIG/Lambda? With this approach, I see when want to update an API of one service then we are deploying API of all services which means our regression will include testing access of all services. On the other hand creating separate APIG/Lambda per service we will end up with multiple resources (and multiple accounts) to manage, can be operational burden later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A microservice is autonomously developed and should be built, tested, deployed, scaled, ... independently. There are many ways to do it and how you'd split your product into multiple services. One pattern as an example is having the API Gateway as the frontdoor to all services behind it, so it would be its own service.

A lambda usually performs a task and a service can be composed of multiple lambdas. I can't even see how multiple services can be executed from the same lambda.

It can be a burden specially if there is no proper tooling and processes to manage all systems in a automated and escalable way. There are pros and cons for any architecture, but the complexity is definitely reduced for serverless applications since all compute is managed by AWS.

AWS actually has a [whitepaper](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/microservices-on-aws.pdf) that talks about microservices on AWS.